# MouseHook Deletes Text on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos

I'm working on a Java FX application that involves using a moushook to capture text selected with the mouse. This was worked without problems when compiled and run with Java 8, but I'm currently required to use Java 10, which has caused an issue to arise on Mac OS X (there is no problem when run on Windows 10).

The problem is that when text is selected from a document (e.g. text in TexEdit) the selected text is deleted and replaced with 'c', rather than being copied. This doesn't happen every time, but does happen very frequently.

I've stripped the mouseHook class down to a very basic test case that shows the problem:

MouseHook class ---------------------------------------------------------

```
package problem;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputListener;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class MouseHook implements NativeMouseInputListener
    {
        private static MouseHook mouseHook = null;

        private Robot mouseRobot = null;

        private boolean mouseLeftButtonDown = false;
        private boolean dragged = false;

        private MouseHook()
        {
            //disable console output from JNativeHook's internal logger (mouse-tracking, etc)
            java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
            logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
        }

        public static synchronized MouseHook getInstance()
        {
            if(mouseHook == null)
            {
                mouseHook = new MouseHook();

                GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(mouseHook);
                GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseMotionListener(mouseHook);
            }

            return mouseHook;
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e)
        {
            //If left button pressed, set mouseLeftButtonDown and look-out for dragging
            if(e.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                mouseLeftButtonDown = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent e)
        {
            //only record a drag if left mouse button is held down.
            //NativeMouseEvent doesn't say which button was the source, hence test the variable.
            if(mouseLeftButtonDown)
            {
                dragged = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e)
        {
            //copy text if the mouse was dragged while the left mouse button was held down.
            if(e.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                final Timer timer = new Timer("ReleaseDetect");

                timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if(dragged)
                        {
                            copy();
                            dragged = false;
                        }

                        mouseLeftButtonDown = false;

                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e)
        {}

        @Override
        public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent e)
        {}

        private synchronized void copy()
        {
            try
            {
                if(mouseRobot == null)
                {
                    mouseRobot = new Robot();

                    mouseRobot.setAutoDelay(100);
                    mouseRobot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
                }

                if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac"))
                {
                    mouseRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
                    mouseRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    mouseRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    mouseRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
                }
                else
                {
                    mouseRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    mouseRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    mouseRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    mouseRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                }

                Thread.sleep(250);

                Transferable t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);

                if(t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
                {
                    String activeContent = (String) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                    System.out.println(activeContent);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Class to run the example--------------------------------------------------------

```
package problem;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;

public class Runnit
{
    private static MouseHook mouseHook;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch(NativeHookException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot set up the NativeHook listener on the GlobalScreen");
        }

        mouseHook = MouseHook.getInstance();
    }
}
```

---

I'm using Oracle's Java 10.0.2 and jNativeHook 2.1.0, with Mac OS High Sierra (10.13.6) on a Mac mini.

The problem seems to be to do this java.awt.Robot, rather than jNativeHook.

e.g. If I replace the VK_C keyPress/Release with VK_B the mousehook deletes selected text and replaces it with 'b'.

My gut feeling was that the VK_META keypress was being ignored. I tried putting in a delay before that keypress, but it makes no difference.

I've also tried using a different mouse, and someone else's Macintosh, but the problem still happens. As I said, it only happens on Mac OS X, not Windows 10, when the code is compiled and run with Java 10.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas as to whether this is a lost cause, or if there is a work-around. It may be that I've missed something obvious, as I normally work on Windows and have lsss familiarity with Mac OS X.